# Google Apps Script: How to remove a link from a document

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm having trouble to remove a link from a Text element.

Calling `.setLinkUrl(null)` on it seems to work, but makes the document crash! You can see it happening with this tiny google script:

```
function test() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var text = body.appendParagraph("link").editAsText();
  text.setLinkUrl(null);
}
```

Running it then trying to edit the document gives me a "File unavailable" error. Also tried to set remove the link with `.setAttributes`, but same error.

Is there a way to remove a link or just generally reset the styles on a text element?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using setLinkUrl(null) now fully removes the link.  Example:

```
function myFunction() {
  var a = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  a.getBody().editAsText().appendText('abc');
  var b = a.getBody().findText('abc');
  b.getElement().asText().setLinkUrl('https://google.com');
}

function myFunction2() {
  var a = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var b = a.getBody().findText('abc');
  b.getElement().asText().setLinkUrl(null);
}
```

Comment: Did this ever get addressed? I'm struggling to find a way to do this.

Comment: No, it's still an open issue. https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=5243

Comment: What does Google mean by the "Triaged" status? And why aren't they on Github yet? :P

Answer (score 0):

I found an horrible trick to remove LinkURLs from text, it made the trick for me :)

```
var textRangeElement = body.findText("yourpattern");
var textElement = textRangeElement.getElement().getText();
textRangeElement.getElement().setText(textElement);
```

Comment: This removes all styles from the element, so isn't an option if you're trying to preserve other styles in the element.